# how to hide the navigation bar in delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to hide the navigation bar in my app. I am using tab bar controller in app.

For hiding, I am using below code on all tab first controller (and all controller also just to avoid error).

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

This is hiding the navigation bar on each controller but I can see that navigation bar is getting hided at top. I see that effect.

However I don't want to see that effect and hence I want to hide navigation bar always when the app is loaded.

Hence I was trying to handle this in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` OR `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`.

Any idea how can I do this in delegate?

**Main motto is not to see that effect on each tab. Atleast on home tab is fine, but I don't want to see on all tabs.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `animated:NO` instead:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];        
}


[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
                                                               ^^^
```